# VBA: How to Use an Array to Extract the Corresponding Value in Another Array?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two arrays - one containing revenue for each year (R) and a second containing the corresponding free cash flow margin (FCF). I want to create a simple function that will output the corresponding FCF margin when revenue surpasses $2bn.

```
Function YearSalesSurpassTwoBillion(R As Range, FCF As Range)

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To R.Columns.Count

    If R(i) >= 2000 Then Exit For
Next i

YearSalesSurpassTwoBillion = FCF(i)

End Function
```

Comment: a simple index/match will do this.  Is vba really necessary?

Comment: Probably can be done in Excel but I'm trying to learn the basics of VBA.

Comment: You're not using arrays here - you are accessing the worksheet ranges directly.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using arrays here - you are accessing the worksheet ranges directly.

If you want to use arrays:

```vba
Function YearSalesSurpassTwoBillion(R As Range, FCF As Range)
    Dim i as Long, arrR, arrFCF

    arrR = R.Value       'get 2-D arrays...
    arrFCF = FCF.Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrR, 2)
        If arrR(1, i) >= 2000 Then 
            YearSalesSurpassTwoBillion = arrFCF(1, i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim but not working. Firstly, I received a compile error: 'duplicate declaration in current scope' as a result of assigning Dim i as Long and then as an Integer. Secondly, the arrays are horizontal so I don't think this works. I tried to flip your code around for it work, e.g., 1 to UBound(1, arrR) and the same for arrFCF(1, i) but not worked.

Comment: That does it Tim. Thank you very much.